# Is it safe to write dBCommand.AddParameter even though I'm not going to use it in a query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Scenario: my query variable is dynamic, there are 4 possible values for that depending on the report type (`_reportType`). Meaning there are 4 different queries and some of it doesn't have `@STAFF` in the `where` condition, so my question is, is it safe to just leave my

```
dBCommand.AddParameter("@STAFF", staff)
```

there or should I include if else condition just to be safe?

Like this

```
if(_reportType == 1) 
{
    dBCommand.AddParameter("@STAFF", staff);
}
else if (_reportType == 2) 
{
    //code
}
else if (_reportType == 3) 
{
    //code
}
else
{
     //Don't add dBCommand.AddParameter("@STAFF", staff);
}
```

Is it safe just to leave `addParameter("@STAFF", staff)` even though I'm not going to use it in a query?

Example I'm going to write

```
dBCommand.Initialize(string.Format(query, "RetailTable"), batch);
dBCommand.AddParameter("@STAFF", staff);
```

But the query value doesn't have `@STAFF` in the `WHERE` condition

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Still prints my report though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should generally be ok to specify unused parameters, aside from the minor overhead of sending the value to the server. The exception is if you execute DDL queries that have a restriction of being the only statement in the batch (e.g. `CREATE VIEW`). Those would fail due to the parameter.

Comment: @beginnerlaravelvue StackOverflow of course :). There are some good tips on [bad SQL habits](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival/) from Aaron Bertrand; although that's from the SQL side rather than C#.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 glaring bad practices in your approach:

**1. Generating dynamic query within the code.**

This approach has many drawbacks and possible security loopholes. You should almost always avoid doing that.

Please go through the following links to understand this more:

https://codingsight.com/dynamic-sql-vs-stored-procedure/
https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/112/SQL-injection-attack-and-prevention-using-stored-procedure

**2. Trying to use generic Where Clause that fits all your variations.**

This approach is disaster in waiting, regardless of the query being written in your application code OR in a Stored Procedure.

This is an ugly code-smell and a maintenance nightmare.

No developer can ever be 100% sure that there will not be any change required during the lifespan of the application due to a simple fact that the client WILL need enhancements on regular bases.

So, even if this approach may work for you for a small period of time, this will blow back.

Assume, over the period, there are few more filter parameters added due to new requirements. Now, imagine how your code would look like and the possibilities it creates of problems you may get if they are not handled properly. Specially when YOU are not making those changes. Scary, right?

Always write code that will not only be easier to read and understand, but also easy to enhance and maintain, regardless of the person writing the code.

So, IMHO, you should add those `if-else` conditions OR use `switch-case` blocks to safeguard yourself and your client. It may look overkill in the start, but will surely payoff in future.

Hope this help!